# Why are my Buttons not appearing in Tkinter Frame?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Hey I want yo use frames in my tkinter fullscreen window ,but everything in the Frame is not appearing. May someone help?

```py
mainmenu = Frame(root)
mainmenu.pack(side='left')
    
PlayBT = Button(mainmenu,text="Play",font=("Arial",40))
PlayBT.place(x=0,y=100)
    
SettingsBT = Button(mainmenu,text="Settings",font=("Arial",40),command=settings)
SettingsBT.place(x=0,y=206.25)
    
QuitBT = Button(mainmenu,text="Quit",font=("Arial",40),command=root.destroy)
QuitBT.place(x=0,y=312.5)
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason for why you are using `.place`? Try adding `height=350, width=100` inside the `Frame(root)`

Comment: Ayo thank you that is much needed not the exact measurements but I needed to make the Frame bigger

Comment: The reason you can't see your buttons is that `.place` doesn't tell the frame to get bigger so it doesn't. You can manually set the width and height of the frame to fix that.

Comment: May you make an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `tk.Frame` doesn't resize itself to fit the widgets that are put inside it when `.place` is used. I suggest trying to use `.pack` or `.grid`. Another option is to manually add the `height` and `width` parameters inside the `Frame(root)`. That will tell the frame to resize itself to that width/height.